# Including existing files to Visual studio 2022, keeping folder structure

Tags: file, include, structure, external, visual-studio-2022

How can I include external files into a visual studio project and keeping the folder structure? I have a folder holding a huge sum of files, nicely ordered into folders and sub folders but when I copy this into my project, only the files are being copied, not the folders. Do I need to create all the folders ('filters' in VS?) myself and copy each file one by one into the correct sub folder?

Seems like a very basic functionality to me?

Thanks.

Comment: Using Windows Explorers, I'm able to simply copy and paste any folder into the directory of where my project files are and Visual Studio will automatically show the folder (with the correct subdirectory structures) in Solution Explorer.

Comment: The behavior will depend on which project type (e.g. language and platform) you are using.  I believe C++ (based on your mention of "filters") uses a purely virtual hierarchy, i.e. does not map to disk.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677756/visual-studio-c-use-filters-as-directories

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy. Indeed, I use C++. I've found some useful information in the link/question.